# Density of division of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, with densities $f_X (x)$ and $f_Y (x)$. What is the density of $X / Y$?

Assume $P(Y = 0 ) = 0$.

Comment: You might need to assume that $f_Y(0) = 0$ which is not quite the same as $P(Y=0)=0$ which is true as long as you assume that densities do not have atoms.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in general is not trivial. If they are standard normals, the answer is a Cauchy distribution.

Comment: They don't need to be standard normals. Wouldn't a change of variables work?

Comment: @user181586 yes and no: what is the distribution when X has mean 100 and Y has mean 3?

Comment: I don't see what you mean. Wouldn't the change of variables be an universal solution?

Comment: @user181586 what change of variables would you use for my example?

Comment: I would change from the random vector $(X,Y)$ to $(X/Y,Y)$. But I am not sure about the result I get...

Comment: @user181586 but isn't the first of the pair the distribution you are originally trying to determine? in general, if its not two standard normals, it gets tricky or intractable.

Comment: yes, but after the change of variables: can't I take the first distribution of the pair as the result?

Comment: @user181586 conceptually, yes, but it won't be exactly cauchy. See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution

Comment: aah... curious...

Comment: what about this solution?

http://math.tntech.edu/ISR/Introduction_to_Probability/Distributions_of_Functions/thispage/node16.html

Comment: @user181586 again, that is for a specific transformation, and it works out to a nice formula. I'm not saying there are no nice solutions, just that they are special cases.